# How I can create new app in Xcode with this architecture

Tags: ios, xcode

Please see attached image. In `Xcode` what this red circled area is called? and how we create multiple version of APP as shown in fig. Please give me a hint or tell, how it is structured? The app is fully developed I just want to update few URLs and create a new application and upload.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing an example of multiple targets project.
Each item in the red circle is a separate target.

From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html):

> A target specifies a product to build and contains the instructions
> for building the product from a set of files in a project or
> workspace. A target defines a single product; it organizes the inputs
> into the build system—the source files and instructions for processing
> those source files—required to build that product. Projects can
> contain one or more targets, each of which produces one product.

If you want to create the new target in `Xcode`:
choose `View` > `Navigators` > `Show Project Navigator`, click on `+` icon at the bottom left corner and add new target from the menu, or
choose `File` > `New` > `Target`

Comment: Thats usually how complete and "Lite" app versions work?

Comment: @KarloA.López yep, I had such experience developing "free" and "paid" versions of an app. One project with 2 targets - target for free (lite) features, and target for the full set of features.